# Excel2LaTeX on Mac - "Invalid procedure call or argument" error

Tags: excel2latex

I know several topics are dealing with errors related to Excel2Latex but I could not solve my problem so I take a chance here.

I have a French version of Excel 2011 (14.6.6) on Mac OS.X.El Capitan (10.11.6) and I've tried unsuccessfully to run Excel2Latex on an Excel table I want to convert.

I followed the steps described at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/ but when I run it, I have an error saying "invalid procedure call or argument" ("argument ou procédure d'appel invalide", in french) and the debugger pops up.

Has anybody solved this issue recently ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try the [latest version](https://github.com/krlmlr/Excel2LaTeX/raw/master/Excel2LaTeX.xla). If no luck, you can [open an issue with the developer](https://github.com/krlmlr/Excel2LaTeX/issues), it seems there were/are some issues with localized Excel versions.

Comment: Please don't download the `.xla` file directly from the program sources, as that isn't guaranteed to be up-to-date. Much better to check for a [new release](https://github.com/krlmlr/Excel2LaTeX/releases), and then to check the [issues](https://github.com/krlmlr/Excel2LaTeX/issues) to see if a temporary hotfix has been issued.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the package developer. This is related to [issue #6](https://github.com/krlmlr/Excel2LaTeX/issues/6) on GitHub, which is caused by a corrupted `PROJECTwm` stream, which ultimately traces back to the tool I use to package the `.xla` file. This is fixed in the recent [v3.4.2 release.](https://github.com/krlmlr/Excel2LaTeX/releases)